# Apache vhost local request

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I got 2 sites configured via apache vhost like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
    ServerName  www.site1.com
...
    
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
    ServerName  www.site2.com
...
```

I would like to know how to make a request to those sites locally from the server that is running apache. I can connect to the server via SSH and then I would like to do for example wget. When I use for example [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) domain as a request then it goes outside to the Internet and then it comes back to the server. I would like to check the site just locally without the request going outside the server. I guess I can use local IP address to get the response from the first site, but I do not know how to access the other one.

Answer (score 1):

If Apache is listing on all interfaces (which it is by default), you can just add the host names to `/etc/hosts` file and access them via the loop back interface.

```
#/etc/hosts
...

127.0.0.1 www.site1.com www.site2.com

...
```

Then try from the server terminal to access is via `wget` or `curl`

```
$ curl -Iv https://www.site1.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `/etc/hosts` or you should use `curl` with option `resolve`.